# Wordpress banner (header) won't resize

Tags: wordpress

I'm using WordPress and my banner/header won't resize to mobile but the rest of the site and page does resize.

Comment: You'll have to add some code. What media queries do you have in CSS, what's the markup of your banner in HTML?

Comment: I'm just starting to learn to code. I can copy the code around the banner and paste it here if that helps.

Comment: Ps thanks for the help

Comment: That will help. Have you already added media queries? You'll need those to make it scale with window/screen size. There are plenty good tutorials about them, I'm sure you'll be able to jump right in.